# Issue with retrieving from shared preference. Overwrites the current marker title android studio

Tags: android, google-maps, sharedpreferences

I have implemented a map that allows users to view different markers and also add marker via long click. Looking at several guides I have managed to get it to work, sort of. The marker gets added via long click if the user has entered a title in the edit box. You can leave the app and come back and all is good its saved. The problem comes if i add a second marker and close and open the map, both markers now have the same title and the previous marker title has been over written.

```
    @Override
public void onMapLongClick(LatLng latLng) {
    addressEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextAddMarker);
    title12 = addressEditText.getText().toString();

    if (title12.length() > 2) {
        MarkerOptions markerOpt1 = new MarkerOptions()
                .title(title12)
                .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f);
        markerOpt1.position(latLng);

        mMap.addMarker(markerOpt1);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Marker Added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        locationCount++;

        /** Opening the editor object to write data to sharedPreferences */
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        // Storing the latitude for the i-th location
        editor.putString("lat" + Integer.toString((locationCount - 1)), Double.toString(latLng.latitude));

        // Storing the longitude for the i-th location
        editor.putString("lng" + Integer.toString((locationCount - 1)), Double.toString(latLng.longitude));
        editor.putString("title", addressEditText.getText().toString());


        // Storing the count of locations or marker count
        editor.putInt("locationCount", locationCount);

        /** Saving the values stored in the shared preferences */
        editor.commit();

    } else if (title12.length() < 1) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Enter title at the top left.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Then here is where I retrieve and draw the marker on to the map

```
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    this.mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);

    // Opening the sharedPreferences object
    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("location", 0);

    // Getting number of locations already stored
    locationCount = sharedPreferences.getInt("locationCount", 0);


    // If locations are already saved
    if (locationCount != 0) {

        String lat = "";
        String lng = "";
        String title = "";

        // Iterating through all the locations stored
        for (int i = 0; i < locationCount; i++) {

            // Getting the latitude of the i-th location
            lat = sharedPreferences.getString("lat" + i, "0");

            // Getting the longitude of the i-th location
            lng = sharedPreferences.getString("lng" + i, "0");


            SharedPreferences myPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            String mDate =  sharedPreferences.getString("title", "title");


            //Toast.makeText(this, lat + "," + lng, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            double lat3 = Double.valueOf(lat).doubleValue();
            double lng3 = Double.valueOf(lng).doubleValue();

            position1 = new LatLng(lat3, lng3);
            drawMarker(position1,mDate);
        }

    }
```

So I would like that when the user adds multiple markers each has a unique title added from the edit text... 
I am not the best programmer so please be kind, all help will be appreciated. thankyou in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you `for` loops you are storing and retrieving your data from prefs and using the loop counter `i` in your lat and lng key names, but you are not doing the same for the `title`.

For example to retrieve each individual `lng` you are using:

```
sharedPreferences.getString("lng" + i, "0");
```

But to retrieve `title` you are just using:

```
sharedPreferences.getString("title", "title");
```

So the same value for title will be retrieved on every iteration of the loop.

Comment: Thanks for responding! I tried what you said     String mDate =  sharedPreferences.getString("title" + i, "title"); and also String mDate =  sharedPreferences.getString("title" + i, "0"); the outputs for the title was "title" and "0" on all markers.

Comment: You need to implement this where tou are *"storing AND retrieving"*. So where you are storing the `title` you'll need something like `editor.putString("title" + i, addressEditText.getText().toString());`

Comment: While i got you here am I allowed to ask you a question regarding a different related problem i have?

Comment: The StackOverflow guidelines say you should put it in a new question.
There are thousands of people online looking through the questions, so it should get answered fairly quickly (as long as you write the question well, providing all relevant info like you did with this one.)